# Is it ok to ask if a summary of a subject is correct

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, asking-questions, scope

In the process of learning a subject it happens, quite often, that I would like to post a summary of my understanding to get feedback from the community. Is that acceptable?

I do not feel knowledgeable enough to publish in a blog, and just wish to confirm what I understand. What are the Stack Overflow objectives concerning this type of summary "Question" ?

#### Considerations

Bad :

- Stack Overflow is not a forum,
- Stack Overflow focus and aim at detail questions on any subject,

Ok if:

- Your text is not longer than x lines, ...

Comment: That doesn't sound like the type of thing that would make for a good Stack Overflow question.

Comment: At least he asked whether it would be on-topic first though.

Comment: @DennisMeng, is there any ethical rules, somewhere ?

Comment: Other than what's spelled out in the help center? I can think of a few resources that are as good as definitive nowadays, but not a whole lot that would pertain to this kind of thing.

Comment: @DennisMeng, ok, thanks.

Comment: Fun fact: we once had a question called "What StackOverflow is not". It is now deleted.

Comment: Pretty much everything you need to know can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).  Beyond that, it all falls under a broad, general category of *"respect the community's time."*

Comment: The length of a question is not really related to whether or not it's appropriate (and certainly doesn't make inappropriate questions appropriate) (but if it starts getting long, you may just be asking a bad question - not a rule, but a general guideline).

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Is that because "stack overflow is not about what stack overflow is not"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of asking if your understanding is correct, ask the real question. What is bothering you about the topic?

Avoid just making a bullet list of the issues that are bothering you though.

If you cannot seem to figure out an aspect of the topic you are learning, then try to narrow it down so someone can clarify one issue at a time. This is a learning process, being able to narrow down a topic to a single issue is important. It will allow you to get the feedback you are seeking and it will also allow you to solve your own problems at times.

The first thing to do is find the exact piece of code that is bothering you. The next thing to do is to create an example with as little code as possible which highlights the issue you do not understand.

If you can create an example which highlights your issue then the odds are in your favor to get a good answer and a better understanding of that specific issue. Doing this for a range of subtopics will allow you to further your learning of the topic as a whole.

Further reading: [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) by Jon Skeet

Comment: To be more specific, I have an understanding of many information fetch from different sources.  The problem is not the validity of each details, but rather the relations between these informations.  I guess I indirectly answer "yes" from your comment, it make sense to ask this type of question, as long as the question is well spelled out, and other details grayed out.  I will go ahead and see what happen.

Comment: @Alain - Also, if you are looking for feedback on code you have written, consider checking out [code review exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You can also ask about design or not-strictly-code topics at [Programmers.SE], @Alain. Be aware that similar standards for question specificity, answerability, and overall quality apply just as strongly there as on SO.